# Entity Framework - retrieve only if records that match in other table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

The title is a little confusing, but I couldn't think of another way to word this.

So, as the title says, I'm using Entity Framework Core in my ASP.NET application. I have a few tables/models that are relevant for this question (I'll leave out irrelevant fields/properties):

The `Customer` table:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The `Menu` table:

```
public class Menu
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int? ParentMenuID { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The `CustomerMenu` table:

```
public class CustomerMenu
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int MenuID { get; set; }
    public int? CustomerID { get; set; }
}
```

My goal is to have standard menu structure (menu records are linked to each other in a child/parent relationship), but customers will only see parts they are linked to, via the `CustomerMenu` table.

So, my questions is, what is the best way to getting the children menu records that are associated with a given customer?

Getting the child menus of an menu is easy enough - I can do that with this code:

```
var childMenus = _context.Menu.Where(m => m.ParentMenuID == id);
```

But I only want to return the menu records that are linked to a given customer via the `CustomerMenu` record/model.

So, my question is this: is there a way I can do this in a single call (retrieve child menu records that are associated with a customer), without having to manually cycle through each menu record and check if it is linked to a customer?

Thanks.

Comment: So you want to `join` the two tables?

Comment: See msdn sample for join : https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Comment: Well yes, I'm trying to do a join. But as I'm using code first with entity framework, its a little different to what I'm used to. So I guess I'm asking how to do a join from within entity framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

```
(from a in context.Menu
               join c in context.CustomerMenu on a.ParentMenuID equals c.ID

               select a,c).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll give this a shot.

Comment: Thanks. That was almost exactly what I wanted. I needed to add a "where" clause to the Menu bit, and change the join statement to "a.ID equals c.MenuID", but it seems to be giving me the results I was after.